# Inqualitiy with exponent

Tags: inequality, exponential-function, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, number-comparison

I was trying to prove this inequality $\exp(\frac{1}{\pi})+\exp(\frac{1}{e})\geq 2 \exp(\frac{1}{3})$ My attempt was using AM-GM mean $\exp(\frac{1}{\pi})+\exp(\frac{1}{e})\geq2 \exp(\frac{1}{2\pi e})$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $$\pi+e<6,$$ by AM-GM and C-S and  we obtain:
$$e^{\frac{1}{\pi}}+e^{\frac{1}{e}}\geq2\sqrt{e^{\frac{1}{\pi}}\cdot e^{\frac{1}{e}}}=2\sqrt{e^{\frac{1}{\pi}+\frac{1}{e}}}\geq2\sqrt{e^{\frac{4}{\pi+e}}}>2\sqrt{e^{\frac{4}{6}}}=2e^{\frac{1}{3}}.$$